# How did they came up with this simplification of given differential equation? (kepler's first law proof)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

So for the proof of Kepler's first law they make a simplification of a differential equation, but I don't get how they come up with that simplification. It goes like this

$$2\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+r\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=0$$
once simplified (which I don't understand) they came up with this answer
$$\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}\left(r\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2\right)=0$$
could someone please explain to me what they did?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply the chain rule to the derivative in your second equation.

Comment: [Possibly related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722435/solving-textbfrt-fracgmrt3-textbfrt/3722688#3722688)

Comment: @Karl thanks for your reply but what I actually want to know is how would you come up with this equation? Are there any steps I can apply on the first equation?

Comment: I'd say it's more of a "trick". There's no set of steps that always works for solving differential equations - you sometimes have to just "notice" that an expression can be rewritten in a useful way. The more examples you see, the better you'll get at it.

Comment: ok thank you :)

Comment: Oops sorry I meant product rule. Looks like it's too late to edit my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\color {red} {2r}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=0$$
More simply:
$$r'\theta '+2r\theta ''=0$$
Multiply by $\theta ':$
$$r'(\theta ')^2+2 r \theta '\theta ''=0$$
Then you have:
$$r' (\theta ')^2+r ((\theta ')^2)'$$
Finally:
$$(r((\theta ')^2))'=0$$

---

But this
$$2\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+r\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=0$$
Is :
$$2r'\theta ' +r \theta ''=0$$
$$2r'r\theta ' +r^2 \theta ''=0$$
$$(r^2 \theta ')'=0$$
The two equations you wrote are not giving the same result.