# Solve differential equation $\ddot{x} = -a \frac{x}{|x|^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, celestial-mechanics

Came across this in a physics problem. Let $x$ be a plane vector dependent on time $t$. Let $\ddot{x}$ be the second order derivative of $x$ against $t$. Let $|x|$ be the Euclidean norm of vector $x$ Solve

$\ddot{x} = -a \frac{x}{|x|^3}$

I'm trying to start by solving this as an ordinary differential equation $y^{''} = -a \frac{y}{|y|^3}$ where $y$ is a scalar. But even this ODE is quite difficult to handle, especially the $|y|$ part.

Comment: See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722435/solving-textbfrt-fracgmrt3-textbfrt/3722688#3722688)

Comment: This is a [classical central force problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem#Polar_coordinates) in the plane. The standard approach is to switch to polar coordinates and solve the resulting system of two differential equations using a first integral. Do not waste time on $y$ as a scalar, it is a completely different 1D problem which is of no help.

Comment: Look also at the other search results under keyword "Kepler" and tag [tag:celestial-mechanics].

Comment: It is equivalent to $x''+sign(x)\frac{a}{x^2} = 0$. For positive $x$ we have $x'' x'+a \frac{x'}{x^2} = 0$