# Reference for the differential equation $(\ddot{x}(t), \ddot{y}(t))=-G/r^3(x(t), y(t))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Does anyone know where I can find the deduction of the differential equation

$$(\ddot{x}(t), \ddot{y}(t))=\frac{-G}{r^3}(x(t), y(t))$$

where $t\mapsto (x(t), y(t))$ describes the moviment of a body in a plane around a spherical mass? Here $G$ is a constant (should be the gravitational constant) and $r$ is the distance from the sphere.

Thanks.

Comment: This is derived from the second law of the dynamics.

Comment: The general idea for inverse-square laws is that you have a central source. Its total influence is independent of the radius, but spread out over the whole sphere area. As that scales with $r^2$, the influence density has to scale with $r^{-2}$. Then multiply by the central unit vector to get the third power of the radius in the denominator.

Comment: This is just Newton's law of gravitation,
$$F_{\mathrm G}=\frac{-GM}{r^2}$$
So 
$$m\ddot{\boldsymbol x}=\frac{-GM}{|\boldsymbol x|^2}\frac{\boldsymbol x}{|\boldsymbol x|}=\frac{-GM}{|\boldsymbol x|^3}\boldsymbol x$$

Comment: See the solution here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722435/solving-textbfrt-fracgmrt3-textbfrt/3722688#3722688

Comment: Thanks yuo all, that was helpful!