# Initial Value Problem for a Particle Subject to a Coulomb Force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Suppose that a particle of charge $q$ is exactly one meter from an oppositely charged particle (same magnitude of charge). The initial velocity of this particle is $0$. From Coloumb’s law and Newton’s second law, the initial value problem will be the following:

$r”(t) = -\frac{kq^{2}}{m}\cdot \frac{1}{(r(t))^{2}}$, $r(0)=1$, $r’(0)=0$, where $m$ is the Mass of the particle, and $r(t)$ is the distance between the particles $t$ seconds after release. Does there exists closed form solution to this IVP? If $r’(0) \neq 0$, a closed form solution can be found by writing $r(t) = A (C\pm t)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. But if $r’(0)=0$, then $C$ must be zero, and $r(0)$ also will have to be zero, contrary to the initial condition. Does another closed form solution exist? Or, even if a closed form solution does not exist, can it be written in terms of a series? I am unsure how to rewrite $\frac{1}{(\sum_{n = 1} a_{n}x^{n})^{2}}$ as a series. Why or why not?

Comment: The equation for the particle you've provided is incorrect.  The acceleration is inversely proportional to the square of the distance.

Comment: This is an equivalent problem to [Newtonian Gravitation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722435/solving-textbfrt-fracgmrt3-textbfrt/3722688#3722688).

Comment: @K.defaoite. Yes, but in this case, I am assuming that $r’(0)=0$ is parallel to $r(t)$.

Comment: There is a closed form available, however it is an implicit representation. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=r%27%27%5Bt%5D%3Da%2Fr%5Bt%5D%5E2)

Comment: Yes, but this closed form solution will only yield a solution of the form $y’(0)=0$ and $y(0)=-1$. Could the solution somehow be translated so that $y(0) = 1$? We can’t just add a constant because the equation is nonlinear.

Comment: Does there exist an expression (doesn’t have to be closed form) for the solution to the IVP $y’’ = -\frac{1}{y^{2}}$ , $y’(0) = 0$, $y(0)=1$?

Comment: Also, where does the closed form $(\frac{y\sqrt{c_{1} + \frac{2}{y}}}{c_{1}}- \fracc{2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{c_{1}+\frac{2}{y}}}{\sqrt{c_{1}}}}{c_{1}^{\frac{3}{2}})^{2}=   (c_{2} + x)^{2}  $